# Twilio Flex UI: How do I wrap TaskListItem with another component so that I can revise firstLine and secondLine?

Tags: reactjs, twilio, twilio-flex

In Twilio Flex UI, when receiving a phone call or SMS, my goal is to leave the [TaskListItem](https://assets.flex.twilio.com/docs/releases/flex-ui/1.33.0/TaskListItem.html) design the same, yet update the `firstLine` and `secondLine`
[props](https://assets.flex.twilio.com/docs/releases/flex-ui/1.33.0/TaskListItem.html#.TaskListItemProps) with updated custom async content for the incoming task.

At first, I was thinking I could update `manager.strings` with the information I needed, yet that updates for ALL tasks at once so that won't work. I could also append extra info at the bottom of a `TaskListItem` without disturbing default Flex UI functionality, yet my project requirements prefer text updates in the `firstLine` and `secondLine` in the `TaskListItem` itself. I could also rewrite the full `TaskListItem` component to replace, yet that's duplicate work that might not be needed.

Now I'm working to just wrap the `TaskListItem` component and pass through the props. Eventually, I'll customize the `firstLine` and `secondLine` props with an async update, yet I'm struggling to get the basic wrapper to work. I don't get any errors, yet when I set my UI status to available for the tasks to show (one SMS message for now), I get these console logs followed by a freeze and Flex crash (IDs anatomized):

```
[2023-11-06T17:23:56.541Z] Worker %s received Event: worker.activity.update. Proceeding to update ... WK00000000000000000000000000000000
twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:679 [2023-11-06T17:23:56.607Z] Worker %s received Event: reservation.created. WK00000000000000000000000000000000
twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:679 [2023-11-06T17:23:56.607Z] Attempting to create and insert Reservation into Worker %s reservations map. WK00000000000000000000000000000000
//... then it crashes after a while
```

Here's the plugin code I'm testing:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import * as Flex from '@twilio/flex-ui';
import { FlexPlugin } from '@twilio/flex-plugin';
import { TaskListItem, TaskListItemProps } from '@twilio/flex-ui';

const PLUGIN_NAME = 'MyPlugin';

export default class MyPlugin extends FlexPlugin {
    constructor() {
        super(PLUGIN_NAME);
    }

    async init(flex: typeof Flex, manager: Flex.Manager): Promise<void> {
        const MyTaskListItemWrapper = (
            props: TaskListItemProps
        ): JSX.Element | null => {
            useEffect(() => {
                console.log('this will get called once on first render, yet does not when attempting to pass through TaskListItem');
                // I'm going to async update the `firstLine` and `secondLine` TaskListItem eventually after an extra API call, leaving all else the same.
            }, []);

            return <TaskListItem {...props} />;
            /*
            return (
                <div>
                    I can return this, yet returning TaskListItem results in a
                    Flex UI crash.
                </div>
            );
            */
        };

        flex.TaskListItem.Content.replace(
            <MyTaskListItemWrapper key="MyTaskListItemWrapper" />
        );
    }
}
```

If I log props, I'm not seeing much data there. Perhaps I need to wrap in `withTaskContext` and/or something else with UI API. I'm sure I'm missing something. Any ideas on how to proceed?

UPDATE:
This also fails with the same crash after learing about [addWrapper()](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/work-with-components-and-props#addwrapper-api):

```
        Flex.TaskListItem.Content.addWrapper(
            (OriginalComponent) => (originalProps) => {
                const updatedProps = {
                    ...originalProps,
                    firstLine: 'Custom First Line',
                    secondLine: 'Custom Second Line',
                };
                const CustomBanner = () => <div>Customer Banner</div>;

                return (
                    <>
                        <CustomBanner />
                        <OriginalComponent {...updatedProps} />
                    </>
                );
            }
        );
```

However, I'm also noticing since I'm working in TypeScript that `Flex.TaskListItem.Content.addWrapper` expects `ComponentWrapper<TaskListItemChildrenProps>`, which different than `TaskListItemProps`. Perhaps I need to wrap its children here instead of the component itself? I'll race you to an answer.

UPDATE:
I have been able to wrap other similarly listed components without issue. For example:

```
        flex.IncomingTaskCanvas.Content.addWrapper(
            (OriginalComponent) => (originalProps) => {
                const updatedProps = {
                    ...originalProps,
                    secondLine: 'Custom Second Line',
                };

                return <OriginalComponent {...updatedProps} />;
            }
        );
```

Is it possible that there's an issue with `TaskListItem` or am I missing something?

UPDATE: It looks like TaskListItem props are mostly read only. I may have to find an alternate solution unless I'm misunderstanding. I'm still open to thoughts.

```
export interface TaskListItemProps {
    readonly visible?: boolean;
    readonly selected?: boolean;
    readonly selectedTaskSid?: string;
    readonly onSelected?: (taskSid: string) => void;
    readonly icon?: string | React.ReactNode;
    readonly iconColor?: string;
    readonly actions?: Array<React.ReactElement<any>>;
    readonly firstLine?: React.ReactNode;
    readonly secondLine?: React.ReactNode;
    readonly extraInfo?: React.ReactNode;
    readonly large?: boolean;
    readonly itemSize?: TaskListItemSize;
}
```

Comment: [addWrapper](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/work-with-components-and-props#addwrapper-api) might be what I'm looking for. Confirming.

Comment: That wasn't the full answer hmm.